# Codes for walking on platforms along with jumping using actionscript 2.0

Tags: actionscript

I want to know the shortest and most understandable code for walking on platforms using actionscript 2.0.

I know there are multiple ways in doing it but my method becomes too tedious when a lot of platforms are needed.

So I just want to know:

1.) A code for walking on platforms and an easy way for me to add another working platform

2.) Code for jumping.

Codes I've been using so far:

```
//Gravity Variables

var grav:Number = 0;

var gravity:Number = 5;

var touchingGround:Boolean = false;

//Jump Variable

var maxJump:Number = -40;

//Code for player1

p1.onEnterFrame = function() {

//Gravity code

p1._y += grav;

grav += gravity;

while (ground.hitTest(p1._x, p1._y, true)) {

    p1._y -= gravity;

    grav = 0;

}

if (ground.hitTest(p1._x, p1._y+5, true)) {

    touchingGround = true;

} else {

    touchingGround = false;

}

//Jumping

//Jump Code

if (Key.isDown(Key.UP) && touchingGround) {

    grav = maxJump;
```

Optional, but can someone explain this part for me:

```
while (ground.hitTest(p1._x, p1._y, true)) {

    p1._y -= gravity;

    grav = 0;

}
```

Comment: It's 2015 when you asked this and 2017 now, when the Community bumped it (I've thumbed the only answer so that doesn't happen again). Stop using AS2 and upgrade to AS3. For the love of all that is good and right in the world, if you're going to use a dead platform, at least use the *current version.* <Cue "flash isn't dead" comments>

Answer (score 1):

If you place all of your interactive objects (floor pieces etc.) inside of the 'ground' movieclip, then you only need to check the ground movieclip for the hit test, so it should not be too tedious when a lot of platforms are needed, as long as they are all inside of that ground movieclip.

1&2) This is how I would do it. For this set up you need two MCs on the stage, one named 'man' (short for jumpman) and the other being 'ground' (to act as the thing we can jump and stand on). The following can go on a frame in the root of your movie.

```
_root.man.onLoad = function(){
    //the speed in which the man is currently falling
    this.gravity = 0;
    //if the man is currently jumping, keeps from double jumping
    this.jumping = false;
}

_root.man.onEnterFrame = function(){
    // if you hit the jump button
    if(Key.isDown(Key.UP) && !this.jumping){
        //change the 'gravity' of the character, so he is repelled from the floor
        this.gravity = -3;
        this.jumping = true;
    }
    // if you hit the left button
    if(Key.isDown(Key.LEFT)){
        // move left
        this._x-=5;
    }
    // if you hit the right button
    if(Key.isDown(Key.RIGHT)){
        // move right
        this._x+=5;
    }

    //every frame, let gravity push you down the screen
    this._y+=this.gravity;

    // if you are hitting the ground
    if(_root.ground.hitTest(this._x,this._y,true)){

        //no more jumping for you
        this.gravity =0;
        this.jumping = false;

        //if you want him to butt up to the top of the hittestable object
        //move him up until he is no longer hitting the ground.
        while(_root.ground.hitTest(this._x,this._y,true)){
            this._y-=0.1;//this can be changed to be as granular as needed, lower number is more accurate but more calculations
        }
    }


    //the longer you are falling for, the faster you go
    this.gravity+=0.1;
    //the fastest you can fall, aka terminal velocity
    if(this.gravity>5) this.gravity = 5;

}
```

Bonus Point:

While works like this: When the argument for while is true, while does what is in its brackets instantly, after doing so, it checks the argument again and repeats. If while is used even within a 'on enter frame' event, it will execute over and over until the argument is false, BEFORE it goes to the next frame (a common mistake). If you never stop the while look from running (aka if you run: while(true){/*something*/} ), then the game will freeze, because it will not progress to the next frame until that function is completed, which it never will complete in that scenario, because it is always true and keeps running over and over again.

In English the code that you selected reads like this: Check if p1 is hitting ground, and if so, then change the p1's position relative to gravity, and reset grav to zero, then recheck if p1 is hitting ground and repeat as needed, until p1 is no longer hitting the ground.

Hope that helps!